# Visual Studio 2010 Language Support

Tags: ide, programming-languages, visual-studio-2010, editor

I want to be able to develop code using Visual Studio 2010. I just got VS2010 and I'm not able to get the languages I want on it. The main reason that I'm asking this is that I'm trying to migrate to ONE IDE that does it all for me. Thus far eclipse has been doing a good job, but I've been informed that VS2010 is better and I'm trying to get into the groove of that standard

So my question is two-fold.

1. I am not able to find a complete list of languages supported by VS2010. What are these languages?
2. How can I get VS2010 support for:

   1. Python/IronPython
   2. C/C++/C#/XNA
   3. Java

My Googling has given me no promising/definitive results.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia (search Visual Studio 2010):

"Visual Studio supports languages by means of language services, which allow the code editor and debugger to support (to varying degrees) nearly any programming language, provided a language-specific service exists. Built-in languages include C/C++ (via Visual C++), VB.NET (via Visual Basic .NET), C# (via Visual C#), and F# (as of Visual Studio 2010[3]). Support for other languages such as M, Python, and Ruby  among others is available via language services installed separately. It also supports XML/XSLT, HTML/XHTML, JavaScript  and CSS. Language-specific versions of Visual Studio also exist which provide more limited language services to the user. These individual packages are called Microsoft Visual Basic, Visual J#, Visual C#, and Visual C++."

Comment: Note that Visual Studio *still* doesn't support `C99`.